# How to make a custom segue?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a couple of `UIViewcontroller`s with buttons on each one that change you from one view controller to another. But whenever I click those buttons, the ViewControllers pop up as a Pop Over, and I need them to switch to a different screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `Presentation` attribute of your ViewController from `Automatic` to `Current Context`.

[image: Description]

[image: Description]

In this context, you don't need a custom segue; those are defined programmatically anyway.

[See this](https://agostini.tech/2019/03/18/custom-transitions-using-segues/), and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html) for more clarification.